# How to extract text (PyPDF2) from specific location/span on PDF

Tags: python, pdf, text, scrape, pypdf

I have already extracted a text from a PDF page to Text variable.
I'm looking to extract the number that comes after the string 'your number is' (14 length string was matched on span (982,996):

```
object=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filename)
Text = PageObj.extractText()
PageObj = object.getPage(0) 
ResSearch = re.search(String, Text)
```

I'm getting a result: span = (982, 996) match = 'your number is'. Now all I need is to scrape the three digit text that comes after that ('your number is **105**'), as the files are changing daily and the fetching should be dynamic.
Thank you everyone !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about regex not pdf itself. Under the assumption that at most one match per page you can use `search`, otherwise use `findall`. Have a look at the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) on how to use group, section with `(...)`.

```
import PyPDF2, re

filename = '' # 

pdf_r = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(open(filename, 'rb'))
text = pdf_r.getPage(0).extractText() # from 1st page or make a loop

if p := re.search(r'your number is (\d{3})', text):
   my_number = int(p.groups()[0]) # as int
```

Use PyPDF4, the syntax is the same and it doesn't "have" such `extractText` issue:

- from the [doc](https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PageObject.html):
  *This works well for some PDF files, but poorly for others, depending on the generator used. [...] Do not rely on the order of text coming out of this function, as it will change if this function is made more sophisticated.*

Comment: Many thanks for your help ! I've ran the suggested code, the issue is that it fetches a P parameter with a NoneType object value, hence the my_number parameter doesn't fetch back any value.

Comment: Ahhhhh I did a stupid mistake in the `if`! I corrected it: substitute `match` with `compile`, sorry for that [already edited]

Comment: Hi again and thank you for your help and patience. I'm still trying to wrap my head around that as this, after changing the search into compile, I'm getting a "unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' " failure message. So the P is still a NonType object, hence I believe my_number cant pull and exert grouping and searching. I also tried using input() on both P and my_number

Comment: the _walrus operator_, `:=` was introduced in python3.8. Which version are you running?

Comment: I edited it, let me know it works now. I did a mess while copy-paste process of my solution and writing the post